# Logarithm of an infinite series

Tags: logarithms, infinity

I am curious about simplifying the following expression:

$$
\log\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}{}}{n!}\bigg)^{v}, v>0, x>0 
$$

Is there any rule to simplify a summation inside the log?

Also, is there any way to derive the following expression:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\log\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}{}}{n!}\bigg)^{v} 
$$
or
$$
\frac{d}{dv}\log\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}{}}{n!}\bigg)^{v} 
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Does the infinite series $\sum_0^\infty \frac{y^n}{n!}$ look familiar to you?  If so, can you think of a way of rewriting your infinite summation so it's in this form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exponential function $e^y$ is defined as

$$ e^y:=\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {y^k \over k!}.$$

So your sum is simply (by setting $y=x^{\frac{1}{v}}$)

$$e^{x^{\frac{1}{v}}}.$$

Summary

- If you mean to calculate the logarithm of the sum raised to the power of $v$, log(sum^v):

$$\begin{align}
\log \left(\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {x^{\frac{k}{v}} \over k!}\right)^v\right)&=v\log \left(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {x^{\frac{k}{v}} \over k!}\right)\\
&=v\log\left(e^{x^{\frac{1}{v}}}\right)\\
&=vx^{\frac{1}{v}}\log e \\
&=vx^{\frac{1}{v}}.\end{align}$$

- If you mean to calculate the logarithm of the sum *all* raised to the power of $v$, (log(sum))^v:

$$\begin{align}
\left(\log \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {x^{\frac{k}{v}} \over k!}\right)^v&=\left(\log e^{x^{\frac{1}{v}}}\right)^v\\
&=\left(x^{\frac{1}{v}}\right)^v\\
&=x^{\frac{v}{v}}=x.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate your efforts. So, you are sure your answer is correct.

Comment: You can check here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function and here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialFunction.html

Comment: @gowarth Why this is incorrect?

Comment: @Azzo Then study the two answers below.

Comment: @juniven I did.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Everyone agrees it is x.

Comment: If you take $e^{x^{\tfrac{1}{v}}}$ and raise it to the $v$-th power and then apply the logarithm, you'll get $vx^{\tfrac{1}{v}}$ not $x$. Of course, the problem wants you to take $e^{x^{\tfrac{1}{v}}}$, apply the logarithm, and then raise it to the $v$-th power. You got the right answer, but applied the steps in the wrong order.

Comment: In the current revision of your answer, the step "$v\log\left(e^{x^{\tfrac{1}{v}}}\right) = v\dfrac{1}{v}\log e^x$" is incorrect. Note that $v\log\left(e^{x^{\tfrac{1}{v}}}\right) = vx^{\tfrac{1}{v}}$.

Comment: Ok, your answer is now correct under the assumption that the problem is $\displaystyle\log\bigg(\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}{}}{n!}\bigg)^{v}\bigg)$ as opposed to $\displaystyle\bigg(\log\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}{}}{n!}\bigg)\bigg)^{v}$, which is what another answer assumed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. @JimmyK4542

Comment: It's  a good answer now, covering both possible interpretations. The way it's currently written in the question, it's certainly the first expression. But there's always a possibility that the OP may have misrepresented what they actually meant to ask...

Answer (score 3):

The exponential function is defined by
$$e^z = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Hence we have that
$$\log\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n/v}}{n!}\right)^v = \log\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x^{1/v})^n}{n!}\right)^v = \log\left(e^{x^{1/v}}\right)^v = (x^{1/v})^v = x. $$

Now that we've simplified the original expression, it should be easy to compute the derivatives.

Comment: I upvote also this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start over. As the other answers already worked it out, the expression inside the logarithm, or rather inside the big parentheses, simplifies because it's an instance of the series for the exponential function:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(x^{1/v}\right)^n}{n!}=e^{x^{1/v}}.$$

But then remember what $a^{b^c}$ means: $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$, **not** $(a^b)^c$ (which would be equal to $a^{bc}$). So we get

$$\log\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}}{n!}\right)^v=\log\left(e^{x^{1/v}}\right)^v=v\log\left(e^{x^{1/v}}\right)=vx^{1/v}.$$

From that, you can take the derivative either with respect to $x$ or with respect to $y$. Let us know if you'd like to see that worked out.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is more appropriate!

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$ e^{x} =\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac {x^k}{k!}$$ In our problem we can write our expression as $$\log(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{v}}}{n!})^v =\log(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(x^{\frac {1}{v}})^n}{n!})^v$$ Thus we have, $$\log(e^{x^{\frac {1}{v}}})^v = (x^{\frac {1}{v}})^v=x$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: I upvote coz this is correct

Comment: @juniven My heartfelt thanks.

Comment: How did $x^{\frac{1}{v}}$ become $\frac{x}{v}$??? Do you actually think that e.g. $16^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{16}{2}$???